# When editing data in popup, data of only first row is displayed for all rows in knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

I am using knockoutjs to show multiple record in table using foreach loop, in previous version of our software when user clicks on row edit it shows the input fields within the tr so the user can edit. Now my task is to show the input fields in bootstrap popup when user clicks the username of that particular tr. 
The issue is when i click on any row it shows the data of the first row only in modal popup.
Following is my full page code

```
<div class="hidden cstm-right-sc" data-bind="css: { hidden: false }" id="AdminPanel">
<div id="CriteriaPanel" class="criteria">
    <div class="criteria_filter">
        <h3>Filter Criteria</h3>
        <div class="filter-criteria_innr">
            <label for="Company">Company</label>
            <select autofocus="autofocus" data-bind="options: Companies, optionsCaption: '(Select)', optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: CompanyId, visible: !Busy()" id="Company"></select>
            <span data-bind="visible: Busy"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="CriteriaSummaryPanel" class="criteria cstm_sctn">
    <div class="criteria_innr">
        <h3>Community Resident Portal - Client Administrators</h3>

        <div class="criteria_contnt">
            <div data-bind="if: CompanyId()">
                <div data-bind="text: 'Company: ' + CompanyName()"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="report-table" data-bind="if: CompanyId()">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Login
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <!-- ko if: $root.EditId() !== null -->
            <!--<th>
                New Password
            </th>
            <th>
                Active
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>-->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Users">
        <tr>
            <!-- ko if: $root.EditId() === Id() -->
            <td><span data-bind="click: $root.Edit, text: LoginName, css: { clickable: $root.EditId() === null }" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span></td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: EditEmail" />
            </td>

            <!--<td>
                <input data-bind="value: Password, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind="checked: IsApproved, visible: $root.EditId() !== 0" type="checkbox" />
                <span data-bind="visible: $root.EditId() === 0">N/A</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="InlineEditActionPanel">
                    <span data-bind="click: $root.Save, css: { clickable: $root.IsValid }">Save</span>
                    <span class="clickable" data-bind="click: $root.CancelEdit">Cancel</span>
                </div>
            </td>-->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: $root.EditId() === Id() -->
            <td><span data-bind="click: $root.Edit, text: LoginName, css: { clickable: $root.EditId() === null }" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Email"></td>
            <!-- ko if: $root.EditId() === 0 -->
            <!--<td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>-->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <tr class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
            <td colspan="3" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Client Admins</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div>
                        <input data-bind="visible: Id() === 0, value: LoginName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                        <span data-bind="visible: Id() !== 0, text: LoginName" style="display: none;"></span>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input data-bind="value: EditEmail, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input data-bind="value: Password, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input data-bind="checked: IsApproved, visible: $root.EditId() !== 0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox">
                        <span data-bind="visible: $root.EditId() === 0">N/A</span>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="InlineEditActionPanel">
                            <span data-bind="click: $root.Save, css: { clickable: $root.IsValid }">Save</span>
                            <span class="clickable" data-bind="click: $root.CancelEdit" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="attr: { colspan: $root.EditId() === null ? 4 : 5 }">
                <span data-bind="click: $root.Add, css: { clickable: $root.EditId() === null }" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Add new user</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
            <td colspan="3" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Client Admins</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div>
                        <input data-bind="visible: Id() === 0, value: LoginName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                        <span data-bind="visible: Id() !== 0, text: LoginName" style="display: none;"></span>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input data-bind="value: EditEmail, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input data-bind="value: Password, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input data-bind="checked: IsApproved, visible: $root.EditId() !== 0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox">
                        <span data-bind="visible: $root.EditId() === 0">N/A</span>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="InlineEditActionPanel">
                            <span data-bind="click: $root.Save, css: { clickable: $root.IsValid }">Save</span>
                            <span class="clickable" data-bind="click: $root.CancelEdit">Cancel</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Please help me i am new to knockout js.
It's very important.

Comment: Can you provide an HTML output. So that we may have an idea of what we are dealing with.

Comment: Sure will provide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a modal with ID `myModal` multiple times inside `foreach: Users`, so you have multiple modals with the same ID.  It's opening the first modal it finds with that ID, which is the first record.  You need to uniquely name the modals, something like

```
<td>
    <span data-bind="click: $root.Edit, text: LoginName,
          css: { clickable: $root.EditId() === null },
          attr: {'data-target', '#myModal' + Id()}"
          data-toggle="modal"></span>
</td>
```

and

```
<tr class="modal fade" data-bind="attr: { id: 'myModal' + Id()}"
    role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: Having multiple modals is not an elegant way of handling things. You should have only one modal, and put the data into that modal using **JQuery**

Comment: Thanks Paul that solution looking great will try that. @Ruzgar yes you are right but when i take modal popup out of foreach loop it does not work bcoz data-binds of input depends on loop.

Comment: That is not necessarily true. You can use `data-id` attribute and then call it using **JQuery's** `event.relatedTarget` object. And bind it into a function of **Bootstrap Modal** like `on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {`. This is a matter of choice of course.